# Create border around dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem:** I would like to create a border surrounding a drop-down box if left blank when the user enters a zip code. Otherwise, leave it how it is.

Currently, how it works is if the user enters a zip code and selects the submit, an alert will pop up and results will not be displayed until user selects the miles. This only occurs if user selects to find a locations using a zip code. Otherwise, it will populate the results.

Here is the form along with the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $zip = $('#zip');
  var $city = $('#city');
  var $hospital = $('#hospital');
  var $miles = $('#miles');

  $zip.on("change",function(){
   $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
   $hospital.val('').trigger('input');
  });

  $city.on("change",function(){
   $zip.val('').trigger('input');
   $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });

  $hospital.on("change",function(){
   $zip.val('').trigger('input');
   $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });
  $zip.one("change", function(){
   $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });
 });
 function checkTextField() {
  var distance = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
  var zip = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["zip"].value;
 
  if(zip && !distance){
   var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
   alert(alertMessage);
   return false; //Does not submit form
  }
  else
   return true;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-body">
  <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form">
   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>  
            <option value=""></option>
        <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
        <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
       </select></div>

   <hr />
   <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group"><!---<select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>--->
      <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance">
       <option value={{v.value}} ng-repeat="(k , v) in miles track by $index">{{v.value}}</option>
      </select>
       <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
     <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" onclick="return checkTextField();" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should work. 
Modified you checkTextField() function to highlight miles field if it is empty

> document.getElementById("miles").style.border = " solid #000000"

Plus your miles dropbox has oninput tag as so

> oninput = "unHighlight()"
>   Which calls the un-Highlight function to remove the box in case the value of it anything other than "".

reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp
           http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $zip = $('#zip');
  var $city = $('#city');
  var $hospital = $('#hospital');
  var $miles = $('#miles');

  $zip.on("change", function() {
    $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected', true).trigger('input');
    $hospital.val('').trigger('input');
  });

  $city.on("change", function() {
    $zip.val('').trigger('input');
    $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });

  $hospital.on("change", function() {
    $zip.val('').trigger('input');
    $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });
  $zip.one("change", function() {
    $miles.val('').trigger('input');
  });
});

function checkTextField() {
  var distance = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
  var zip = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["zip"].value;

  if (zip && !distance) {
    var alertMessage = "Please Select Distance When You Are Entering A Zip Code.";
      document.getElementById("miles").style.border = " solid #000000"
    alert(alertMessage);
    return false; //Does not submit form
  } else
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
          <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>
          <option value=""></option>
          <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
            <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
          </cfoutput>
        </select>
      </div>

      <hr />
      <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <!---<select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>--->
              <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" oninput = "unHighlight()">
                <option value={{v.value}} ng-repeat="(k , v) in miles track by $index">{{v.value}}</option>
              </select>
              <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" onclick="return checkTextField();" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" />
      </div>
      <script>
       
        function unHighlight() {
         
          var miles =  document.getElementById("miles").value;
                      
         try{
        
            if(miles != ""){
         document.getElementById("miles").style.border = "none"
          }
        }
           catch(err)
             {
                          document.getElementById("miles").style.border = "none"
               }
         
                    }
      </script>
      
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ JagannathanAlagurajan: I would like the highlight the border after I click submit

Comment: @ JagannathanAlagurajan: I would like to highlight the border after I click submit and have the border to be gone when user selects a mileage

Comment: @RobertoFlores There you go, modified it! Should highlight the drop down box after you clear the alert.